# How does ESPN control espn.go.com without controlling go.com

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, tld

How does ESPN control the domain `espn.go.com` if they don't control the tld of `go.com`. How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whois shows that Disney controls go.com.  ESPN is [majority owned by Disney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assets_owned_by_Disney#ESPN.2C_Inc.).

Answer (score 6):

`espn.go.com` is delegated to a separate set of nameservers by `go.com`, which means that the manager of `go.com` has ceded management of `espn.go.com` to a potentially different party:

```
espn.go.com.            300     IN      NS      ns02.espn.go.com.
espn.go.com.            300     IN      NS      ns01.espn.go.com.
espn.go.com.            300     IN      NS      ns03.espn.go.com.
```

These nameservers might be run by ESPN, in which case they have created the `A` record for `espn.go.com`:

```
espn.go.com.            30      IN      A       68.71.216.176
```

I can't find any evidence that `ns0{1..3}.espn.go.com` are actually run by ESPN however -- they may be run by the same people as `go.com` itself. If this is the case, then `go.com` have simply created this DNS record which points to ESPN's servers. ESPN don't control the DNS zone in this case, they just run the HTTP server which the record happens to point to.